# Randomly spawn SKNode on the x position?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

I have a game and I can't seem to get the node to randomly spawn on x position, it will randomly spawn but often will go off screen and the game is then useless and have to restart it:

```
func addEnemy () {
    //enemy
    let minValue = self.size.width / 8;
    let maxValue = self.size.width-20;
    let spawnPoint = UInt32(maxValue - minValue);

    Enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy")
    Enemy.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 200)

    Enemy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(spawnPoint)), y: self.size.height)
    self.addChild(Enemy)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let min: CGFloat = 15.0
let max: CGFloat = 200.0
let randomCGFloatBetweenMinAndMax = CGFloat(rand())/CGFloat(RAND_MAX)*(max-min)+min
```

or if you prefer

```
let randomCGFloatBetweenMinAndMax2 = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max-min)) + UInt32(min))
```

Comment: thank you so much! i hade to edit it to min = self.size.width / 15.0 and max = self.size.width - 200